# Google Chart API with the lack of data and annotation

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization, pie-chart

Here are 11 customers and its figures. However, when the Google Chart API runs, there are only 7 customers and 1 other. Hence, as the first glance, a user just can see 7 customers and doesn't have the information or the name of 4-left-customer.

What I am looking here is just show all my customers even it got a very small proportion as 0.1% or 0.2%.

```
    ['CustomerName', 'TotalCBM'],
    ['Century Furniture Co.', 2.08],
    ['CTH/Sherrill Occasional', 38.01],
    ['EJ Victor', 0.83],
    ['Emerson Et Cie', 3.46],
    ['Four Hands', 35.36386],
    ['INTERNAL USE', 0.44],
    ['Lillian August', 75.81],
    ['MODERN HISTORY', 18],
    ['MONARCH', 1448.070435],
    ['Resource Décor', 4.07]
```

## **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/huydq91/dVL4N/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `sliceVisibilityThreshold` option to `0` to avoid grouping smaller slices into the "Other" category.  You may not be able to see the smaller slices in the chart, but they will show in the legend.

```
var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0
};
```

ex: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/dVL4N/1/